# Is there a way to reach to a certain byte via pointer in shared memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-memory

I have a pointer that points to first byte of a shared memory which is 66 bytes long. I want to create another pointer that points to a certain byte in shared memory (I'm saying certain byte because I want to get this info from user as integer like:"which byte do you want to reach?"). Is there a way of reaching a certain byte via shared memory's pointer?

Comment: ...`void* anotherPointer = ((char*)pointerToSharedMemory + valueEnteredByUser)`...

Comment: I haven't done any C++ to speak of, but if you have `int *p1, *p2;` why couldn't you do: `p2 = p1 + offset;`  Does pointer arithmetic not work in C++?  (of course you could do a pointer known to be 1 byte instead of `int`.)

Comment: @WordsLikeJared It does, but the results may surprise you. Let's say you're on a machine with 4-byte integers, and p1 points to memory 0x1000. Let offset be 1. After executing p2 = p1 + offset, the value of p2 is 0x1004. That is, the incrementing takes into account how "large" the things that the pointer says it's pointing to are. To do byte-by-byte, you *must* either have a char pointer, or cast it to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shared memory part is irrelevant: what you have is a pointer and you want to increment *n* bytes:

```
T* p = /* pointer to whatever */;
char* nBytesIn = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + n;
```

Or in your case, more safely:

```
char* byte_in_buffer(T* p, std::size_t n)
{
    if (n >= 66)
        throw std::out_of_range("Buffer is only 66 bytes!");

    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + n;
}
```

You need to cast to `char*` because pointer arithmetic dictates that `T* + n` increments `sizeof(T)`; we want to increment by bytes, and `char` is that type (with a size that's always 1).

(Aliasing a value through a `char*` is okay.)

Answer (score 0):

Modification to the above program. with unsigned bytes.

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
byte_t *p = (byte_t *)/*whatever*/

byte_t return_byte(int number)
{
   if(n >= 66 && n <= 0){
       throw std::out_of_range("I don't know what you want");
   }
   byte_t *b = reinterpret_cast<byte_t*>(p)+n;
   byte_t retbyte = *b;
   return retbyte;
}
```